# Summarizing across overlapping dates

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I am trying to see how I can create a variable which summarizes observations across multiple dates.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

sample <- data.table(start = c("2018-12-22 23:00:00",
                               "2018-12-23 06:00:00",
                               "2018-12-22 06:00:00",
                               "2018-12-23 06:00:00"),
                     end = c("2018-12-23 06:00:00",
                             "2018-12-23 13:00:00",
                             "2018-12-23 12:00:00",
                             "2018-12-24 01:00:00"),
                     store = c("A", "A", "B", "B"))

sample[, start:= ymd_hms(start)]
sample[, end := ymd_hms(end)]

sample 

> sample
                 start                 end store
1: 2018-12-22 23:00:00 2018-12-23 06:00:00     A
2: 2018-12-23 06:00:00 2018-12-23 13:00:00     A
3: 2018-12-22 06:00:00 2018-12-23 12:00:00     B
4: 2018-12-23 06:00:00 2018-12-24 01:00:00     B
```

Here, `sample` is a time card of "shifts" used across each store. We see that store A has two observations, each with a start and end time. If there was no "bleeding" across dates (e.g. first observation begins on 2018-12-22 and ends on 2018-12-23), I would simply subtract the start and end times, and sum across the stores to get the total amount of minutes used across each stores. Something like:

```
worked_mins <- sample %>%
.[, date := ymd(substr(start,1,10))] %>%
.[, minutes := end - start] %>%
.[, .(worked_mins = sum(minutes)), by = .(store,date)]
```

However, I am trying to see how to best sum the number of minutes when shifts overlap across multiple days (potentially even >=2 days).

From the above, the desired output would be:

```
worked_mins = data.table(store = c("A","A", "B", "B", "B"),
                         date = c("2018-12-22", "2018-12-23",
                                  "2018-12-22", "2018-12-23",
                                  "2018-12-24"),
                         worked_mins = c(1, 13, 18, 30, 1))

> worked_mins
   store       date worked_mins
1:     A 2018-12-22           1
2:     A 2018-12-23          13
3:     B 2018-12-22          18
4:     B 2018-12-23          30
5:     B 2018-12-24           1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just did, thanks. But that code doesn't work for my desired output.

Comment: Yep. Sorry. It works now, but the problem with this code is that it does not capture the "bleeding" across dates, which I described above.

Comment: You show a name of `worked_mins`, but the differences are really in the order of *hours*, I'm not seeing how minutes equates here.

Comment: @r2evans my mistake. That was sloppy. I apologize. I just put that bit of code to show my intentions. But you are right, it should be in minutes, since start and end times can be written in fractional hours as well.

Comment: No worries, making sure I was understanding correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An updated solution that counts actual time, not just counting hours. This should take into account fractional hours.

```r
library(lubridate) # ceiling_date, floor_date
func <- function(st, en, units = "hours") {
  midns <- ceiling_date(seq(st, en, by = "day"), unit = "day")
  times <- unique(sort(c(midns[ st < midns & midns < en], st, en)))
  if (length(times) < 2) {
    data.table(date = as.Date(floor_date(st)), d = structure(0, class = "difftime", units = units))
  } else {
    data.table(date = as.Date(floor_date(times[-length(times)], unit = "days")), d = `units<-`(diff(times), units))
  }
}

sample[, rbindlist(Map(func, start, end)), by = .(store)
  ][, .(d = sum(d)), by = .(store, date)]
#     store       date          d
#    <char>     <Date> <difftime>
# 1:      A 2018-12-22    1 hours
# 2:      A 2018-12-23   13 hours
# 3:      B 2018-12-22   18 hours
# 4:      B 2018-12-23   30 hours
# 5:      B 2018-12-24    1 hours
```

(The `1 hours` is still a numeric column, it just has a label of its units attached; this can be removed easily by wrapping the `diff` in `as.numeric`.)

`func` works by including midnights between `st` and `en`; creating a `times` ordered vector of these unique timestamps allows us to `diff` across them, then `floor_date` them so that we know the date that each diff started.

You can see what `func` is doing with this quick demo, one that makes the first line a 0-second difference (for testing and validation):

```r
copy(sample)[1, end:=start][, rbindlist(Map(func, start, end)), by = .(store)]
#     store       date          d
#    <char>     <Date> <difftime>
# 1:      A 2018-12-22    0 hours
# 2:      A 2018-12-23    7 hours
# 3:      B 2018-12-22   18 hours
# 4:      B 2018-12-23   12 hours
# 5:      B 2018-12-23   18 hours
# 6:      B 2018-12-24    1 hours
```

Comment: Updated to add `units=` to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Does this achieve what you need?

```
sample %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    worked_hours = map2(start, end, ~seq(.x, .y, "hours") %>% head(-1))
    ) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(worked_hours)) %>%
  select(store, worked_hours) %>%
  mutate(date = floor_date(worked_hours, "days")) %>%
  group_by(store, date) %>%
  count(name = "worked_mins")

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   store, date [5]
store date                worked_mins
<chr> <dttm>                    <int>
1 A     2018-12-22 00:00:00           1
2 A     2018-12-23 00:00:00          13
3 B     2018-12-22 00:00:00          18
4 B     2018-12-23 00:00:00          30
5 B     2018-12-24 00:00:00           1
```