# Updating Dates and Date Intervals in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

Not even sure if I've described the problem accurately in the title, but here goes.

Suppose I have the following data.table/data.frame:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)


DT <- data.table(begin = c("2019-06-01 09:00:00","2019-06-01 09:00:00", "2019-06-01 09:00:00",
                           "2019-06-01 09:00:00", "2016-06-01 09:00:00","2016-06-01 09:00:00"),
                 end = c("2019-06-03 14:00:00", "2019-06-03 14:00:00", "2019-06-03 14:00:00",
                         "2019-06-02 05:00:00", "2019-06-02 05:00:00", "2016-06-01 23:15:00"),
                 person = c("A", "A","A", "B", "B", "C"))

    begin                 end person
1: 2019-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-03 14:00:00      A
2: 2019-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-03 14:00:00      A
3: 2019-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-03 14:00:00      A
4: 2019-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-02 05:00:00      B
5: 2016-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-02 05:00:00      B
6: 2016-06-01 09:00:00 2016-06-01 23:15:00      C
```

This is essentially a dataset summarizing time stamps of when a period began and ended for each person. The number of rows are repeated for each person by the number of days which the time period spans. For example, person `A` has three entries for the same "shift" because their shift spans three distinct dates, 06-01, 06-02, and 06-03. The entries are repeated by the number of dates which the shifts span, but some shifts begin and end within the same day.

What I want is to update the begin and end dates of the above dataset, so that I can see what time each shift began and ended at the *day level*. So the dataset should look like:

```
    begin                 end                person
1: 2019-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-02 00:00:00      A
2: 2019-06-02 00:00:00 2019-06-03 00:00:00      A
3: 2019-06-03 00:00:00 2019-06-03 14:00:00      A
4: 2019-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-02 00:00:00      B
5: 2016-06-02 00:00:00 2019-06-02 05:00:00      B
6: 2016-06-01 09:00:00 2016-06-01 23:15:00      C
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you want to replace every `14:00` (for A e.g.) with `00:00` to reflect a new day? You can use `last` and if the time is not equal to `last`'s time, change that to `00:00`? However, why keep all values? Do they work whole night?

Comment: @NelsonGon, yes that is exactly what I want to do. I am trying to separate out how much is being worked per day, when shifts can span more than one day.

Comment: Doesn't your data suggest the shift is continuous for person A?  What do you get out of parsing a shift that spans 3 calendar days 2019-06-01 09:00:00 through 2019-06-03 14:00:00 into three artificial shifts?

Comment: @NelsonGon, The reason is that I want to be able to see how much minutes of labor was used by day.

Comment: Did user `B` really work from 2016 through 2019?

Comment: @plausibly_exogenous, you've been doing a lot of time/shift work, [summarizing across overlapping dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69843002/3358272) and similar. Part of me wonders if you have arrived to this data problem because of something else you did to previous ranges, perhaps over-summarizing. Is this really a new-problem or are you fixing over-aggregation in a previous step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, fixing the dates (and I already fixed row 5's starting in 2016 and going through to 2019, seems unlikely),

```r
DT[, c("begin", "end"):=lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct), .SDcols=c("begin", "end")]

## we get this
DT <- as.data.table(structure(list(begin = structure(c(1559394000, 1559394000, 1559394000, 1559394000, 1559394000, 1464786000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), end = structure(c(1559584800, 1559584800, 1559584800, 1559466000, 1559466000, 1464837300), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), person = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Second, we then create this function

```r
func <- function(st, en) {
  midns <- lubridate::ceiling_date(seq(st, en, by = "day"), unit = "day")
  times <- unique(sort(c(midns[ st < midns & midns < en], st, en)))
  data.table(begin = times[-length(times)], end = times[-1])
}
```

Lastly, we use it, using `by=.(person)` to preserve that column in the output. I use `DT` since we do not need (or even *want*) duplicates for each shift/day:

```r
unique(DT)[, rbindlist(Map(func, begin, end)), by = .(person)]
#    person               begin                 end
#    <char>              <POSc>              <POSc>
# 1:      A 2019-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-02 00:00:00
# 2:      A 2019-06-02 00:00:00 2019-06-03 00:00:00
# 3:      A 2019-06-03 00:00:00 2019-06-03 14:00:00
# 4:      B 2019-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-02 00:00:00
# 5:      B 2019-06-02 00:00:00 2019-06-02 05:00:00
# 6:      C 2016-06-01 09:00:00 2016-06-01 23:15:00
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you had a typo for row 5 person B (begin 2019 not 2016):

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

> DT <- data.table(begin = c("2019-06-01 09:00:00","2019-06-01 09:00:00", "2019-06-01 09:00:00",
+                            "2019-06-01 09:00:00", "2019-06-01 09:00:00","2016-06-01 09:00:00"),
+                  end = c("2019-06-03 14:00:00", "2019-06-03 14:00:00", "2019-06-03 14:00:00",
+                          "2019-06-02 05:00:00", "2019-06-02 05:00:00", "2016-06-01 23:15:00"),
+                  person = c("A", "A","A", "B", "B", "C"))
>                  
> DT[, `:=`(min=as.numeric(difftime(end,begin, units="mins")), 
+           days=as.numeric(as_date(end)-as_date(begin)+1))][, min_day:=min/days]
> 
> unique(DT)
                 begin                 end person  min days min_day
1: 2019-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-03 14:00:00      A 3180    3    1060
2: 2019-06-01 09:00:00 2019-06-02 05:00:00      B 1200    2     600
3: 2016-06-01 09:00:00 2016-06-01 23:15:00      C  855    1     855
```

Comment: Your output looks nothing like the expected output in the OP.

Comment: True, but it gets him to what he stated he wants - minutes per day” for each person.

Comment: No, that gets them minutes per session, not per day. If it were per day, the first row would be three, one each for `06-01`, `06-02`, and `06-03`.

Comment: Edited answer to show minutes and calendar days in range.  Shows minutes per calendar date in range.  Yes, it's within the session, but certainly reflects minutes per date.  Since OP wanted minutes per date, this would bypass having to re-parse start/end datetimes and just go straight to the desired calculation.